# influxDB v 0.11 restore hangs forever

Tags: restore, influxdb

I am doing a POC on Influx 0.11. Below are the steps I perform to do backup and restore.
    #backup metadata

```
 --> influxd backup /tmp/backup
[Timestamp] backing up metastore to /opt/backup/meta.00
[Timestamp] backup complete

#backing up a particular DB - mydb
--> influxd backup -database mydb /tmp/mydb/
[Timestamp] backing up db=mydb since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
[Timestamp] backing up metastore to /tmp/mydb/meta.00
[Timestamp] backing up db=mydb rp=default shard=12 to /tmp/mydb/mydb.default.00012.00 since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
[Timestamp] backup complete
```

It looks fine until now.
     #remove db and stop the service
     --> influx
     --> drop database mydb
     --> systemctl stop influxd

Restoring metadata
     -->  influxd restore -metadir /var/lib/influxdb/meta /tmp/backup
     Using metastore snapshot: /opt/backup/meta.00

It freezes at this point.
Please advise.

Comment: Version 0.11 is six months old. Why not use a more recent version? Also, does restoring a single database without restoring the metastore work without errors?

Comment: Hi Gunnar - we have installed this version in few clusters and in POC state. Also, I saw this version supports backup/restore. Yeah, I tried restoring just the database, it does but I don't see any data being recovered. Only the DB is restored.

Comment: Backup and restore was only reliable in InfluxDB v0.11 on single nodes. I highly recommend using the latest release (with [InfluxDB Relay](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-relay) if you need high availability).